# wordpress php help - the_author_meta('display_name')

Tags: php, wordpress

Need help with the if statement below. I keep getting a echo/print of my variable.

```
    <?php if (the_author_meta('display_name') == 'johnwayne') { ?>
       <div>Blank</div>
    <?php } ?>
```

When i place this code, it will print/echo "johnwayne" instead of the div..

So basically if johnwayne is the author, i want to show a blank div. If anyone else is the author, show a regular div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the_author_meta displays the info, you want get_the_author_meta